# Error de conexión a base de datos MySQL

Tags: c, windows, odbc

Estoy tratando de conectarme a una base de datos local MySQL, lo intenté hacer siguiendo: https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/blob/master/VC2015Samples/ODBC%20database%20sample%20(linux)/odbcconnector/odbcconnector.c

Estoy utilizando `windows`, por tal motivo agregué la libreria `windows.h`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <string.h>

#define RESULT_LEN  256
#define CHECK_ERROR(e, s, h, t) ({\
            if (e!=SQL_SUCCESS && e != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {extract_error(s, h, t); goto exit;} \
})
void extract_error(char *fn, SQLHANDLE handle, SQLSMALLINT type)
{
    SQLINTEGER i = 0;
    SQLINTEGER NativeError;
    SQLCHAR SQLState[7];
    SQLCHAR MessageText[256];
    SQLSMALLINT TextLength;
    SQLRETURN ret;

    fprintf(stderr, "\nThe driver reported the following error %s\n", fn);
    do
    {
        ret = SQLGetDiagRec(type, handle, ++i, SQLState, &NativeError,
            MessageText, sizeof(MessageText), &TextLength);
        if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
            printf("%s:%ld:%ld:%s\n",
                SQLState, (long)i, (long)NativeError, MessageText);
        }
    } while (ret == SQL_SUCCESS);
}
int main() {

    SQLHENV   henv = SQL_NULL_HENV;   // Environment
    SQLHDBC   hdbc = SQL_NULL_HDBC;   // Connection handle
    SQLHSTMT  hstmt = SQL_NULL_HSTMT;  // Statement handle
    SQLRETURN retcode;
    SQLCHAR strResult[RESULT_LEN];
    SQLCHAR outstr[1024];
    SQLSMALLINT outstrlen;
    int i = 0;
    // Allocate environment handle
    retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);
    CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV)",
        henv, SQL_HANDLE_ENV);
    // Set the ODBC version environment attribute
    retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
        (SQLPOINTER*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLSetEnvAttr(SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION)",
        henv, SQL_HANDLE_ENV);

    retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
        (SQLPOINTER*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLSetEnvAttr(SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION)",
        henv, SQL_HANDLE_ENV);
    // Allocate connection handle
    retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);
    CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC)",
        hdbc, SQL_HANDLE_DBC);
    // Set login timeout to 5 seconds
    SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0);
    CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLSetConnectAttr(SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT)",
        hdbc, SQL_HANDLE_DBC);
    // Connect to data source, replace with your connection string
     retcode = SQLDriverConnect(
        hdbc, NULL, "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=xxx;database=dbprueba",//
        SQL_NTS, outstr, sizeof(outstr), &outstrlen, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

    retcode = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=xxx;database=dbprueba", SQL_NTS, outstr, sizeof(outstr), &outstrlen, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    // Allocate statement handle
    retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt);
    CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT)",
        hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
    retcode = SQLExecDirect(hstmt,
        (SQLCHAR*) "SELECT @@version", SQL_NTS); //DB_NAME()
    CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLExecDirect()", hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    // Bind columns
    retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, &strResult, RESULT_LEN, 0);

    // Fetch and print each row of data until SQL_NO_DATA returned.
    for (i = 0; ; i++) {
        retcode = SQLFetch(hstmt);
        if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
            printf("Result is: %s", strResult);
        }
        else {
            if (retcode != SQL_NO_DATA) {
                CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLFetch()", hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

exit:
    printf("\nComplete.\n");
    // Free handles
    // Statement
    if (hstmt != SQL_NULL_HSTMT)
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
    // Connection
    if (hdbc != SQL_NULL_HDBC) {
        SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
    }
    // Environment
    if (henv != SQL_NULL_HENV)
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
    return 0;
}
```

Desde vs code, le doy a "run code" y obtengo:

```
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `SQLGetDiagRec@32'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to `SQLAllocHandle@12'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `SQLSetEnvAttr@16'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `SQLSetEnvAttr@16'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x21e): undefined reference to `SQLAllocHandle@12'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x276): undefined reference to `SQLSetConnectAttr@16'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x2ee): undefined reference to `SQLDriverConnect@32'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x33c): undefined reference to `SQLDriverConnect@32'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x35d): undefined reference to `SQLAllocHandle@12'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x3ad): undefined reference to `SQLExecDirect@12'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x417): undefined reference to `SQLBindCol@24'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x430): undefined reference to `SQLFetch@4'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x4bc): undefined reference to `SQLFreeHandle@8'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x4d1): undefined reference to `SQLDisconnect@4'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x4e7): undefined reference to `SQLFreeHandle@8'
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaO43tq.o:odbc_connector.c:(.text+0x504): undefined reference to `SQLFreeHandle@8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Traté utilizando `makefile` y haciendo:

```
odbc_conn.exe: odbc_connector.c 
    gcc -o odbc_conn odbc_connector.c -lodbc32
```

al ejecutar desde la terminal :

```
./odbc_conn
```

la salida que obtengo es:

```
The driver reported the following error SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT)

Complete.
```

La cadena de conexión la cree revisando orígenes de datos `ODBC` (64 bits).

Answer (score -1):

1. Change the includes in this order: stdio.h, stdlib.h, windows.h, sql.h, sqlext.h      2. Use cl.exe and also review the chain invocation of the methods: CHECK_ERROR, extract_error

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).